# Linear ordering of directed multigraph of dependencies allowing for duplicates

Tags: algorithm, haskell, graph, topological-sort

## Problem description

1. Given vertices `V` which can be seen as named "propositions".
2. Given weights:

```hs
data W
  = Requires     -- ^ Denotes that a "proposition" depends on another.
  | Invalidates  -- ^ Denotes that a "proposition" invalidates another.
```

In a linear ordering, if A requires B, then B must come before A, conversely, if A invalidates B, then B must come after A.

3. Given a weighted directed multigraph (multidigraph) with at most 2 parallel edges... Where a vertex can only require the inclusion of another vertex once, and only invalidates another vertex once...

```hs
G = (V, E)
E = (V, V, W)
```

4. Or alternatively represented as a directed **cyclic** graph with no self-loops and where the only cycles form directly between one vertex and another. With weights changed to:

```hs
data W
  = Requires      -- ^ Denotes that a "proposition" depends on another.
  | InvalidatedBy -- ^ Denotes that a "proposition" is invalidated by another.
```

Given that vertices may occur more than once in the ordering...
**How can a linear ordering be constructed from such a graph?**

Additionally, if the tail of the linear ordering ends with a vertex V which was included due to being InvalidatedBy another vertex, then it may be omitted if the head of the ordering starts with V.

Some desired properties are:

1. Minimality - there should be as little duplication of vertices as possible
2. Stability - the ordering should be as similar as possible to the order between vertices on the same "level" in which the graph was constructed
3. Run-time complexity - The number of vertices are not that high, but still... the run-time complexity should be as low as possible.

If various algorithms fulfill these to varying degrees, I'd love to see all of them with their trade offs.

Algorithms written in any language, or pseudocode, are welcome.

### Example graphs:

Example graph 1:

```
B `requires`    A
C `requires`    A
D `requires`    A
E `invalidates` A
F `invalidates` A
G `invalidates` A
```

With minimal linear ordering: [A, B, C, D, E, F, G]

Example graph 2:

```
C `requires`    A
C `invalidates` A
B `requires`    A
```

With minimal linear ordering: [A, B, C]

Example graph 3:

```
B `requires`    A
B `invalidates` A
C `requires`    A
C `invalidates` A
```

With minimal linear ordering: [A, B, A, C]

## Naive implementation

A naive implementation constructs a linear ordering by starting with all nodes with no incoming edges and for all of those nodes:

1. fetches all outgoing edges
2. partitions those by requires/invalidates
3. constructs the linear ordering of "requires" and puts that first
4. adds the current node
5. constructs the linear ordering of "invalidates" and adds that.

Here's a Haskell implementation of this description:

```hs
import Data.List (partition)
import Data.Maybe (fromJust)
import Control.Arrow ((***))
import Data.Graph.Inductive.Graph

fboth :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> (f a, f a) -> (f b, f b)
fboth f = fmap f *** fmap f

outs :: Graph gr => gr a b -> Node -> (Adj b, a)
outs gr n = let (_, _, l, o) = fromJust $ fst $ match n gr in (o, l)

starts :: Graph gr => gr a b -> [(Adj b, a)]
starts gr = filter (not . null . fst) $ outs gr <$> nodes gr

partW :: Adj W -> (Adj W, Adj W)
partW = partition ((Requires ==) . fst)

linearize :: Graph gr => gr a W -> [a]
linearize gr = concat $ linearize' gr <$> starts gr

linearize' :: Graph gr => gr a W -> (Adj W, a) -> [a]
linearize' gr (o, a) = concat req ++ [a] ++ concat inv
  where (req, inv) = fboth (linearize' gr . outs gr . snd) $ partW o
```

The ordering can then be optimized by removing equal consecutive like so:

```hs
-- | Remove consecutive elements which are equal to a previous element.
-- Runtime complexity: O(n), space: O(1)
removeConsequtiveEq :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]
removeConsequtiveEq = \case
  []    -> []
  [x]   -> [x]
  (h:t) -> h : ug h t
  where
    ug e = \case
      []     -> []
      (x:xs) | e == x    ->     ug x xs
      (x:xs) | otherwise -> x : ug x xs
```

## Edit: Using DCG, SCC, and topsort

With the algorithm described by @Cirdec :

1. Given a directed cyclic graph (DCG) where edges of form: `(f, t)` denote that `f` must come before `t` in the ordering.
2. Compute the `condensation` of the DCG in 1.
3. Turn each SSC in the `condensation` in 2. into a palindrome.
4. Compute the topsort of the graph in 3.
5. Concatenate the computed ordering.

In Haskell:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE LambdaCase #-}

import Data.List (nub)
import Data.Maybe (fromJust)
import Data.Graph.Inductive.Graph
import Data.Graph.Inductive.PatriciaTree
import Data.Graph.Inductive.NodeMap
import Data.Graph.Inductive.Query.DFS

data MkEdge = MkEdge Bool Int Int
req = MkEdge True
inv = MkEdge False

toGraph :: [MkEdge] -> [(Int, Int, Bool)] -> Gr Int Bool
toGraph edges es = run_ empty nm
  where ns = nub $ edges >>= \(MkEdge _ f t) -> [f, t]
        nm = insMapNodesM ns >> insMapEdgesM es

-- | Make graph into a directed cyclic graph (DCG).
-- "Requires"    denotes a forward  edge.
-- "Invalidates" denotes a backward edge.
toDCG :: [MkEdge] -> Gr Int Bool
toDCG edges = toGraph edges $
  (\(MkEdge w f t) -> if w then (t, f, w) else (f, t, w)) <$> edges

-- | Make a palindrome of the given list by computing: [1 .. n] ++ [n - 1 .. 1].
-- Runtime complexity: O(n).
palindrome :: [a] -> [a]
palindrome = \case
  [] -> []
  xs -> xs ++ tail (reverse xs)

linearize :: Gr Int a -> [Int]
linearize dcg = concat $ topsort' scc2
  where scc  = nmap (fmap (fromJust . lab dcg)) $ condensation dcg
        scc2 = nmap palindrome scc
```

For the graph `g2`:

```hs
g2 = [ 2 `req` 1
     , 2 `inv` 1
     , 3 `req` 1
     , 3 `inv` 1
     , 4 `req` 1
     , 5 `inv` 1
     ]

> prettyPrint $ toDCG g2
1:2->[(False,2)]
2:1->[(True,1),(True,3),(True,4)]
3:3->[(False,2)]
4:4->[]
5:5->[(False,2)]

> prettyPrint $ condensation $ toDCG g2
1:[5]->[((),2)]
2:[1,2,3]->[((),3)]
3:[4]->[]

> linearize $ toDCG g2
[5,2,1,3,1,2,4]
```

This ordering is neither minimal nor valid since the ordering violates the dependencies. `5` invalidates `1`, which `2` depends on. `2` invalidates `1` which `4` depends on.

A valid and minimal ordering is: `[1,4,2,1,3,5]`. By shifting the list to the right, we get `[5,1,4,2,1,3]` which is also a valid ordering.

If the direction of the graph is flipped, the ordering becomes: `[4,2,1,3,1,2,5]`. This is not a valid ordering either... At the boundaries, `5` can happen, and then `4`, but `5` invalidates `1` which `4` depends on.

Comment: How is this different than a topological sort of a directed acyclic graph?

Comment: The point of a topsort of a DAG is to create an ordering such that a vertex only occurs once. Since the directed multigraph has parallel edges with weights modelling a dependency relation which are the inverse of each other, this is really a directed cyclic graph, and to linearize that, duplicates must be included.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the following algorithm will find a minimal string of vertices in linear time:

1. Decompose the graph into its strongly connected components. Existing algorithms do this in linear time.
2. In each strongly connected component each node needs to be listed both before and after every other node. List the nodes `[1..n]` of each strongly connected component in the following order `[1..n] ++ [n-1..1]`
3. Concatenate the strongly connected components together in order by a topological sort. Existing algorithms topologically sort directed acylic graphs like this in linear time.

Comment: For there to be strongly connected components, the directed cyclic graph representation must be used and not the directed multigraph one... correct? Also does `[1..n] ++ [n-1..1]` now form a vertex in a new DAG to be topologically sorted? Do you have any Haskell specific pointers for `FGL` or any other graph library? Many thanks!

Comment: Tried the idea - but unfortunately, it doesn't produce a valid ordering, and it doesn't seem to be minimal either... Perhaps I didn't explain the problem sufficiently well... I updated my question in: "Using DCG, SCC, and topsort" with a test of your suggested algorithm.

Comment: @Centril I definitely don't understand the problem then. How is a palindrome not a valid linear ordering for every strongly connected graph?

Comment: Hmm... I'll try a different route to explain the problem... my concrete use case is that I have a graph of normalisation rules `:: a -> Norm a`. A rule `r1` can depend on another rule `r2` having been run on a term before it: `req r1 r2`. A rule `r1` can also invalidate that another rule has `r2` has fully normalised a term: `inv r1 r2`. I then need to find a linear ordering, which then is composed with `foldl (>=>) pure`. This linear ordering is then run until a fixed point on a term. Thus, the ordering must also hold however you shift it. See the examples of valid and minimal orderings...